# Jenkins Windows slave connection getting terminated with java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException and it reconnects automatically after few mins

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

Jenkins Windows slave connection getting terminated with java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException and it reconnects automatically after few mins.
So the builds are failing with this message. I'm just a batch file(.bat) file containing the code to just ping a machine for 2 hours(ping 127.0.0.1 -n 7200 >nul )
I've latest Java installed in both Master and Slave machine.

Jenkins log link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjzSw.png

Comment: It is easier to read the error message if you include it as text. If you do, please use markup.

Comment: @KajHejer I'm not able to add the log file I've added a picture link Stack overflow is not letting me to add this as code. I'm new to this so I don't know how to add this here

FYI: Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjzSw.png 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/924036/kaj-hejer